# at xampp phpmyadmin after pressing "empty session data" i am not able see all my databases and not be able to create now database

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I am using xampp where in PHPMyAdmin I accidentally press "empty session data" after that I am not allowed to create a new database showing error "access denied for user "@"localhost to create database" and also I am not seeing my previous database,
I think after the empty session I logout from PHPMyAdmin and know I don't know the username and password of PHPMyAdmin because it never asks me to enter the user and password, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try clearing any phpMyAdmin related cookies in your browser (they start with `pma`) or using private browsing mode to try to access phpMyAdmin. If that doesn't fix it, then something else must have changed (such as your phpMyAdmin configuration or MySQL user accounts).

Your problem doesn't make a lot of sense, because the "Empty session data" link is the "[config](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-authentication-modes)" login type equivalent of logging out. Since the username and password are hardcoded in to the configuration file `config.inc.php`, logging out doesn't make sense. For that reason, it also makes no sense that you would be able to log in normally but then not be able to log in again (with the same settings).

XAMPP uses the config authentication so you authenticate through XAMPP itself rather than needing to give your username and password to phpMyAdmin.

You could try logging in to the MySQL command line client using the same username and password that are in `config.inc.php`, just to make sure that user account still exists and has proper permissions. The error message `''@'localhost'` is really strange, because it should take the username from `config.inc.php` and not be blank.

You could also check that the configuration file parses correctly, one way you could do that is by visiting the configuration page directly (such as https://example.com/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php). If the page is blank, it doesn't have any parsing errors, which is good.